# Adjektiv für Mehrzahl ("liebe Erika und Richard" vs "liebe Erika und lieber Richard")

Tags: usage, gender, grammatical-number, adjective-ending

Ist es nicht richtig zu sagen

> "*danke, liebe Erika und Richard*"?

Ich meine sie beide - "danke, liebe (Erika und Richard)" (wie "*danke, liebe Kolleginnen und Kollegen*") und nicht wie "liebe Erika und mir egal seiender Richard".

Aber wenn ich nach Beispielen suche, dann finde ich eher, dass die Form

> "*danke, liebe Erika und lieber Richard*"

verwendet werden soll.

Comment: Weniger eine Frage von "richtig", eher eine Frage von "üblich" und "guter Stil".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Liebe Erika und Richard* ist weniger ein Grammatik- denn ein Stilproblem

Das Stilempfinden deutscher Prägung leidet unter der fehlenden Adjektivkongruenz. Da das Problem nicht lösbar ist, weicht man aus auf *Liebe Erika, lieber Richard*.

Es ist kein Unterschied, ob Erika und Richard durch eine Liebesbeziehung und/oder eine Eheschließung miteinander verbunden sind, oder ob ihr Verhältnis distanzierter ist. (Dies merke ich an, weil es in den Kommentaren diskutiert wurde.)

Natürlich gibt es in freier Wildbahn durchaus Leute, die *Liebe Erika und Richard* schreiben, besonders in sehr formlosen Kommunikationszusammenhängen wie E-Mails. Interessant ist aber, dass es so gut wie niemand in mündlicher Rede **sagen** würde. Und das ist auch schon ein Zeichen dafür, dass es problematisch ist.

Neben der Stilistik ist auch die Höflichkeit ein Faktor: Ein nachlässiges *Liebe Erika und Richard* würde eventuell als unhöflich (da eben unaufmerksam) empfunden.

Aber man würde auch nicht sagen

> *Die grüne Kuh und Elefant

sondern stets

> Die grüne Kuh und der grüne Elefant

Auch ohne den Artikel kann es nicht heißen:

> *Grüne Kuh und Elefant sind seltene Erscheinungen im Tierreich.

sondern nur

> Grüne Kuh und grüner Elefant sind seltene Erscheinungen im Tierreich.

Fazit: Adjektivkongruenz ist dem Deutschen wichtig, und man nimmt auch umständliche Formulierungen in Kauf, um sie zu erreichen.

---

Postscriptum:

Für den Fall, dass Erika und Richard ein Paar sind, gibt es noch folgende Lösung:

> Liebes Paar Erika und Richard!

Oder man zieht sich andere Formen von Gruppenbildung aus der Affäre:

> Liebe Freunde Erika und Richard

Das wirkt aber gestelzt und erfordert dementsprechend einen besonders feierlichen Anlass.

Auch ist es getrickst, weil das Adjektiv sich jetzt auf ein anderes Substantiv bezieht.

Problemlos dagegen:

> Grüne Kühe und Elefanten sind im Tierreich die Ausnahme.

Answer (score 3):

Das liegt daran, dass im Fall der Kollegen und Kolleginnen der Plural für beide Formen `liebe` ist und bei den Namen einmal die feminine und ein anderes Mal die maskuline Form notwendig ist.
Richtig heißt es also `liebe Erika, lieber Richard`, bzw. `liebe Kolleginnen, liebe Kollegen` oder `liebe Kolleginnen und Kollegen`.